# Xamarin binding project structs in external assembly

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie, xamarin.ios-binding

I am using Xamarin binding project and objective sharpie, to bind an objective-c library from this SDK:

http://redpark.com/lightning-ethernet-plus-power-adapter-cable-l4-netp/

I have already had success in binding and using the similar Seriel SDK.
But when I try binding the ethernet SDK I get:

"The type or namespace name 'sockaddr' could not be found. Are you missing a using directory or an assembly reference?"

sockaddr is defined in sys/socket.h

The same goes for following structs:
'fd_set' defined in _fd_def.h and
'timeval' defined in _timeval.h

How do I get it to recognize these structs? 
Has anybody had success binding the Redpark Ethernet SDK?

My binding project is available here:
https://github.com/advcv/redpark.blastclient.binding

Comment: I haven't touched Xamarin's iOS or Android stuff (so there might be something special happening there), but normally C# doesn't touch native headers like that. You'd have to redefine the structs in C# with the help of `StructLayoutAttribute` and optionally `MarshalAsAttribute`. Both structs would have to be aligned the same way and be the same size for everything to work perfectly

Comment: If you have to pass sockaddr as parameter or get it as a result in your ApiDefinition, you have to go to the socket.h and write similar C# structure and put it in the binding project as well. For sockaddr PInvoke.net site might be useful http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/SOCKADDR.html